# Slow Kite Autocomplete in JupyterLab

Tags: python, autocomplete, anaconda, jupyter-lab, kite

So, I have recently installed the kite extension for Jupyter lab, but it seems to have like a 2-3 second delay before suggestions pop up. Compared to other IDEs like vscode, this really slows me down, and I find it rather frustrating. Is there anyway to improve the rate at which basic suggestions (e.g. pd.read_csv) come up? Thanks.

If more information or some sort of a log is needed, I can provide such (although I may need some direction as I have only started using this very recently).

Comment: Kite is AI based, so the delay is probably due to the time it needs to process. In VSCode and most other IDEs the autocomplete is mostly only based on available symbols/module names which is just a fast lookup

Comment: Not an answer, but you could try a recent release of https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp and configure it to use jedi-language-server (the default pyls is not too fast either).

Comment: I see. Is there any other option you know of for Jupyter Lab that may be a better alternative in regard to speed? If not, no worries (I will probably just close the thread).

Comment: I will give that a go and update @krassowski

Comment: Just be aware that the Kite extension and LSP are likely to conflict if installed together (but I guess you would want to have a fresh install using JupyterLab 3.0 anyways) as Kite was originally developed as a fork of LSP (and we did not get to make them compatible with each other yet).

Comment: Related comment on jedi: https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp/issues/272#issuecomment-748604155

Comment: So I tried to install lsp and got this far: https://gyazo.com/8f28f782d71474bea2d3d3135a7c2734
But it doesn't seem to be active / working. Have I done something wrong (kite is disabled)? @krassowski

Comment: It does seem that you have not disabled/uninstalled the kite server (pip-installable) extension

Comment: It still seems to say "kite" in brackets next to the server, but I uninstalled the extensions from labs. Not sure what to do at this point. I think I will close this and make a separate thread @krassowski

Comment: You should probably open an issue on GitHub instead